# generalException - Unexpected exception returned from the service

Tags: onedrive

We are getting this exception from `RestoreMostRecentFromCacheOrAuthenticateUserAsync()` on the `MsaAuthenticationProvider` object from the OneDrive authentication sdk.  When we use `AuthenticateUserAsync()` we are presented with a login prompt requesting email address and password as though it's not recognizing the locally authenticated account on the machine.  Only once we authenticate using `AuthenticateUserAsync()` and grant permissions are we able to use `RestoreMostRecentFromCacheOrAuthenticateUserAsync()` to authenticate the user.  I don't know when this problem started, I just know that we've recently gotten a complaint from a user that changed their password for their Microsoft account, and suddenly encountered the `generalException`.  For test purposes, we removed granted permissions for the app and a few minutes later we encountered the `generalException`.  When we first implemented and tested this sdk, everything worked perfectly.

Is this a problem with the sdk or on the service end?  When can we expect resolution?

Comment: hi which platform are you using the auth sdk?

Comment: Hi, this is for a UWP app.

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.OneDriveSDK.Authentication/

Comment: Hi dabox, is it possible to get some type of confirmation that you've confirmed the problem and are working on it?  Nobody is responding, and that includes the project owners via Nuget.  This breaks expected app functionality, and is very urgent.